# IFTweetLabel in UITableViewCell Subclass not showing

Tags: ios5, uitableview, ios

Right Now I am making a twitter app and I am Using IFTweetLabel. I made a TableViewCell Subclass but When I Run it the label dosent show up.

Here is the .h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "IFTweetLabel.h"

@interface twitterTextCell : UITableViewCell
@property (strong, nonatomic) IFTweetLabel *customtextLabel;

@end
```

And here is the implementation:

```
#import "twitterTextCell.h"

@implementation twitterTextCell
@synthesize customtextLabel;

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
if (self) {
    // Initialization code
    customtextLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
    self.customtextLabel.frame = CGRectMake(240, 60, 345, 109);
    [self addSubview:customtextLabel];

    NSLog(@"Custom Label Text: %@", customtextLabel.text);
}
return self;
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
[super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

// Configure the view for the selected state
}
-(UILabel *)textLabel
{
return nil;
}
```

Here is the code that is in the cellforrow in the tableviewdelegate:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

twitterTextCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {

    cell = [[twitterTextCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle  reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        }

NSDictionary *tweet = [self.timeLineData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    if ([tweet objectForKey:@"text"] != nil) {

        NSString *allText = [[tweet objectForKey:@"text"] stringByDecodingHTMLEntities];

        cell.customtextLabel.numberOfLines = 4;
        cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 4;
        cell.customtextLabel.text = allText;
        cell.textLabel.text = allText;
        cell.customtextLabel.linksEnabled = YES;


        NSDictionary *whoPostedTweet = [tweet objectForKey:@"user"];
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = [whoPostedTweet objectForKey:@"name"];
        NSURL *imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [whoPostedTweet objectForKey:@"profile_image_url"]]];
        [cell.imageView setImageWithURL:imageURL placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        [cell.imageView.layer setCornerRadius:7.0f];
        [cell.imageView.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
        return cell;

        } else {

        [self getTwitterData];
        NSLog(@"nil called(else) ");
        return cell;
        }


    return cell;
        }
```

After all of this only the image and the detailtextview show up. I removing the default textview because If I don't the text shows up normally but it is not the IFTweetLabel. Another thing I have a question about is how do I reposition the detailtextabel so that it is Under the IFTweetLabel. Anything is greatly appreciated, I need help on both of these issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think your problem is you are not allocating customTextLabel.

Just allocate the same before setting the background color in `initWithStyle`.
ie, `self.customtextLabel = [[[IFTweetLabel alloc] init] autorelease]`;